# OS X: What Font is used by NSTextView

Tags: macos, nsattributedstring, nsfont

I'm trying to get the font name (displayname?) and size used by a  NSTextView but the problem is that the name, size etc. seems to be in some kind of internal format. I have some code like this:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextView *tvChatMessage;

...

NSAttributedString* ChatMessage = [self.tvChatMessage textStorage];

NSDictionary* attr = [ChatMessage attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];
NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr[NSFontAttributeName]);
```

The NSLog shows:

> Attr: "ComicSansMS 12.00 pt. P [] (0x6080002410b0)
>   fobj=0x6000001f1a00, spc=3.59"

How do I get from this to the display name "Comic Sans MS", size 12 and "Regular" Typeface?

Comment: `NSFont *font = attr[NSFontAttributeName]`. Then look at the properties `displayName`, `pointSize`, and for Regular, I think that you have to look at `fontDescriptor`.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying much more advanced initializations :-)